# ListView does not update after customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, notifydatasetchanged

In my program I'm trying to update a List of weather conditions into a ListView. I download and store the JSON in an asyncTask, then parse the data into my List during onPostExecute and notifyDataSetChanged. I've looked at several related questions here but I'm not sure what I'm missing. Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<Weather> weatherList = new ArrayList<>();

private WeatherArrayAdapter weatherArrayAdapter;
private ListView weatherListView;
private TextView locationEditText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    weatherListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.weatherListView);
    weatherArrayAdapter = new WeatherArrayAdapter(this, weatherList);
    weatherListView.setAdapter(weatherArrayAdapter);
    locationEditText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationEditText);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Create a URL using the specific city entered by the user
            URL url = createURL(locationEditText.getText().toString());
            //As long as there is not a null url we get the weather
            if(url!=null){
                Log.e("URL", url.toString());
                dismissKeyboard(locationEditText);
                GetWeatherTask getLocalWeatherTask = new GetWeatherTask();
                getLocalWeatherTask.execute(url);
            }
            else{
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),R.string.invalid_url, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void dismissKeyboard(View v){
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

private URL createURL(String city){
    String apiKey = getString(R.string.api_key);
    String baseURL = getString(R.string.web_service_url);

    try{
        String urlString = baseURL + URLEncoder.encode(city, "UTF-8") + "&units=imperial&cnt=16&APPID=" + apiKey;
        return new URL(urlString);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Returns null only if the URL data was malformed
    return null;
}

private class GetWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONObject>{

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try{
            URL url = params[0];
            Log.e("URL", url.toString());
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == 200){
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))){
                    String line;
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuilder.append(line);
                    }
                    connection.disconnect();
                    return new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), R.string.connect_fail, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject weather){
        convertJSONtoArrayList(weather);
        weatherArrayAdapter.updateData(weatherList);
        weatherArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        weatherListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }
    private void convertJSONtoArrayList(JSONObject forecast){
        weatherList.clear();
        try{
            JSONArray list = forecast.getJSONArray("list");
            for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){
                JSONObject day = list.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject temperatures = day.getJSONObject("main");
                JSONObject weather = day.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);
                Calendar hour = Calendar.getInstance();
                hour.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse(day.getString("dt_txt")));

                weatherList.add(new Weather(
                        day.getLong("dt")*1000,
                        hour.getTimeInMillis(),
                        temperatures.getDouble("temp_min"),
                        temperatures.getDouble("temp_max"),
                        temperatures.getDouble("humidity"),
                        weather.getString("icon"),
                        weather.getString("description")));

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Here is my WeatherArrayAdapter.java

```
class WeatherArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather> {

private static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView conditionImageView;
    TextView dayTextView;
    TextView lowTextView;
    TextView highTextView;
    TextView humidityTextView;
    TextView timeOfDayTextView;
    TextView descriptionTextView;
}

//Create a map of used bitmaps to prevent re-downloading previously used bitmaps
private Map<String, Bitmap> bitmaps = new HashMap<>();
private List<Weather> weatherList;

WeatherArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Weather> forecast){
    super(context, R.layout.item_list, forecast);
    this.weatherList = forecast;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.e("ADAPTER", "getView()");
    Weather day = weatherList.get(position);

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.conditionImageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.conditionImageView);
        viewHolder.dayTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView);
        viewHolder.highTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.highTextView);
        viewHolder.lowTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lowTextView);
        viewHolder.humidityTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.humidityTextView);
        viewHolder.timeOfDayTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeOfDayTextView);
        viewHolder.descriptionTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (bitmaps.containsKey(day.iconURL)) {
        viewHolder.conditionImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(day.iconURL));
    } else {
        new LoadImageTask(viewHolder.conditionImageView).execute(day.iconURL);
    }

    viewHolder.dayTextView.setText(day.dayOfWeek);
    viewHolder.highTextView.setText(day.maxTemp);
    viewHolder.lowTextView.setText(day.minTemp);
    viewHolder.humidityTextView.setText(day.humidity);
    viewHolder.timeOfDayTextView.setText(day.timeOfDay);
    viewHolder.descriptionTextView.setText(day.description);

    return convertView;
}



private class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    ImageView imageView;
    LoadImageTask(ImageView view){
        this.imageView = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {

        Bitmap bmp = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try{
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            try(InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()){
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                bitmaps.put(strings[0], bmp);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return bmp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap){
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
public void updateData(List<Weather> weatherList){
    this.weatherList = weatherList;
}

}
```

The Weather.java class

```
class Weather {

final String dayOfWeek, minTemp, maxTemp, humidity, iconURL, timeOfDay, description;

Weather(long timestamp, long timeOfDayMS, double minTemp, double maxTemp, double humidity, String iconName, String description){
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

    numberFormat.setParseIntegerOnly(true);

    this.dayOfWeek = convertTimestampToDay(timestamp);
    this.timeOfDay = convertTimeOfDayToHM(timeOfDayMS);
    this.minTemp = numberFormat.format(minTemp) + "\u00B0F";
    this.maxTemp = numberFormat.format(maxTemp) + "\u00B0F";
    this.humidity = numberFormat.format(humidity) + "%";
    this.iconURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconName + ".png";
    this.description = description;


}

//Given a timestamp of milliseconds since epoch, we create a calendar and derive a day of the week name
private String convertTimestampToDay(long timestamp){
    return new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.US).format(getCalendar(timestamp).getTimeInMillis());
}

//Given a timestamp of milliseconds since epoch, we create a calendar and derive a time of day in hour:minute
private String convertTimeOfDayToHM(long timeOfDay){
    return new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.US).format(getCalendar(timeOfDay).getTimeInMillis());
}

private Calendar getCalendar(long timestamp){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDisplayName()));

    return calendar;
}
}
```

And lastly my list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/conditionImageView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/weather_image"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dayTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="@string/day"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lowTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="@string/low" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/highTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="@string/high" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/humidityTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="@string/humidity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeOfDayTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="@string/time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="@string/desc" />
</GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit** I've fixed the super constructor and I am getting data from the server
Unfortunately, my list view is still blank.
Here is a log of the JSON I get from the API.

```
D/JSON: {"cod":"200","message":0.1604,"cnt":16,"list":[{"dt":1507280400,"main":{"temp":52,"temp_min":50.88,"temp_max":52,"pressure":1031.72,"sea_level":1039.36,"grnd_level":1031.72,"humidity":70,"temp_kf":0.62},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":8.84,"deg":325.503},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-06 09:00:00"},{"dt":1507291200,"main":{"temp":56.17,"temp_min":55.34,"temp_max":56.17,"pressure":1032,"sea_level":1039.58,"grnd_level":1032,"humidity":65,"temp_kf":0.46},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":8.95,"deg":326.001},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-06 12:00:00"},{"dt":1507302000,"main":{"temp":57.13,"temp_min":56.58,"temp_max":57.13,"pressure":1031.96,"sea_level":1039.61,"grnd_level":1031.96,"humidity":57,"temp_kf":0.31},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":8.08,"deg":321.001},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-06 15:00:00"},{"dt":1507312800,"main":{"temp":51.49,"temp_min":51.22,"temp_max":51.49,"pressure":1031.85,"sea_level":1039.49,"grnd_level":1031.85,"humidity":63,"temp_kf":0.15},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":64},"wind":{"speed":3.71,"deg":290.502},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-06 18:00:00"},{"dt":1507323600,"main":{"temp":46.91,"temp_min":46.91,"temp_max":46.91,"pressure":1031.69,"sea_level":1039.4,"grnd_level":1031.69,"humidity":81,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"clouds":{"all":20},"wind":{"speed":4.85,"deg":223.502},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-06 21:00:00"},{"dt":1507334400,"main":{"temp":47.11,"temp_min":47.11,"temp_max":47.11,"pressure":1030.48,"sea_level":1038.22,"grnd_level":1030.48,"humidity":85,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"clouds":{"all":32},"wind":{"speed":7.74,"deg":249.001},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-07 00:00:00"},{"dt":1507345200,"main":{"temp":48.53,"temp_min":48.53,"temp_max":48.53,"pressure":1028.24,"sea_level":1035.82,"grnd_level":1028.24,"humidity":78,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"clouds":{"all":44},"wind":{"speed":9.42,"deg":237.503},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-07 03:00:00"},{"dt":1507356000,"main":{"temp":49.38,"temp_min":49.38,"temp_max":49.38,"pressure":1025.51,"sea_level":1033.19,"grnd_level":1025.51,"humidity":90,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":88},"wind":{"speed":13.04,"deg":237.506},"rain":{"3h":0.715},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-07 06:00:00"},{"dt":1507366800,"main":{"temp":55.61,"temp_min":55.61,"temp_max":55.61,"pressure":1023.56,"sea_level":1031.15,"grnd_level":1023.56,"humidity":89,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":80},"wind":{"speed":14.45,"deg":250.003},"rain":{"3h":0.21},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-07 09:00:00"},{"dt":1507377600,"main":{"temp":61.41,"temp_min":61.41,"temp_max":61.41,"pressure":1021.72,"sea_level":1029.22,"grnd_level":1021.72,"humidity":78,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":76},"wind":{"speed":14.79,"deg":265.003},"rain":{"3h":0.145},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-07 12:00:00"},{"dt":1507388400,"main":{"temp":62.38,"temp_min":62.38,"temp_max":62.38,"pressure":1020.3,"sea_level":1027.8,"grnd_level":1020.3,"humidity":69,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":92},"wind":{"speed":13.76,"deg":280},"rain":{"3h":0.0049999999999999},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-07 15:00:00"},{"dt":1507399200,"main":{"temp":59.14,"temp_min":59.14,"temp_max":59.14,"pressure":1020.7,"sea_level":1028.21,"grnd_level":1020.7,"humidity":69,"temp_kf
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just adding `notifyDataSetChanged()` pass the new `arraylist` as a method to the `weatherArrayAdapter` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

In your **weatherArrayAdapter class** create a method like this

```
 public void updateData( List<Weather> weatherList ){
  this.weatherList=weatherList;
}
```

And in you onPostEcecute add this.

```
convertJSONtoArrayList(weather);
weatherArrayAdapter.updateData(weatherList);
weatherArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also your forecast list is not used anywhere in the list adapter code.Check that once;

**EDIT**:
Your are passing the id of the layout as -1 in the constructor
`super(context, -1, forecast)`.Instead you need to pass the id othe layout that you are trying to inflate.

Comment: I edited the code in my question to reflect these changes but I still get no data in my ListView.

Comment: You are not using that list anywhere..thats why its not showing data

Comment: Instead of  this Weather day = getItem(position) use  Weather day = weatherList.get(position);

Comment: I changed that but it didn't fix the issue. Attempting to Log anything in the getView method of the WeatherArrayAdapter never shows. Is that normal or is that part of the problem?

Comment: are you getting data from the server?check using logs..post the logs here

Comment: I've edited the main post again to show the changes and logs. It's still not working as expected.